# Measurement of Spotify Audio Features

Tags: spotify

I am currently conducting research on American pop songs using Spotify's audio features (e.g., danceability, tempo, and valence...). But, I couldn't find any documentation that contains details about how they measured the features. I know there's a brief description of the features. But, it doesn't tell about any the exact measurement. Could you let me know where I can find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `Echonest` was a music data analysis platform acquired by `Spotify`, and its expertise is being currently used to power up `Spotify` recommendation tools.

`Audio Features API endpoint` extracts a more "High Level" analysis from audio and songs, whereas `Audio Analysis endpoint` extracts more "Low Level" and technical data.

Essentially, "High-level" features are more explicit and make use of clearer semantics -plain english, in order to be easily understood by the layman ("danceability", for instance), but it all comes from Low Level analysis, really.

Here you have some documentation, if you wish to dive deeper into the matter:

http://docs.echonest.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/_static/AnalyzeDocumentation.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the note. But, I can't reach out the link you posted. The message "This site can’t be reached" came out. Could you post the right link again? Thank you.

Comment: try now, please.

Comment: Thank you so much, @data_garden. I just looked through it. But, what I am looking for is how the current audio features provided by Spotify API were measured. For instance, how do they gauge valence, or danceability that are quite subjective?

Comment: like I told you, thats proprietary technology to `Echonest`, and `Spotify`. they would never make their algorithm public, right? it would be like giving their market value away to you. They achieve those subjective classifications by learning and classifying audio extracted from Audio Features data, genre clustering and many more. You'll have to learn from documentation such as the one linked above. no free lunch, my friend.